# Fade in div if other div is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a document ready function without the need of a click, in other words I want the script to be executing all the time on page load.

What I am trying to do is if a div, lets say DIV 1 is not visible on the page then I want my second div, DIV 2 to fade in.

This seems simple but I am having problems getting this to work, please can someone show me where I am going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("HTML BODY").onLoad(function () {
            if($('.noti_box').is(':hidden')){
            $(".advert").fadeIn("slow");

             });

        }});

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off. There is no `onLoad` event in jQuery. You can just put the code to run within the `document.ready` handler and it will execute as soon as the DOM has been loaded. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.noti_box').is(':hidden')) {
        $(".advert").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```